# Is there anything interesting we can do with this fact on iterates of polynomials over a finite ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite ring and $r \in R$ such that $f \in R[X]$ is a min. poly of $r$ over $R$.  Ie. $f(r) = 0$ and $f$ has minimal degree.  In particular if $g(r) = 0$ and $g \in R[X]$, we have that $f \vert \ g(X)$ in $R[X]$.

Since $R$ is finite, the iteration sequence $f^{1}(r), f^{2}(r), \dots$ eventually repeats at $f^m(r) = f^n(r)$, $m \gt n$.  This means that $f \vert \ f^m - f^n$ in $R[X]$.

But we also then have, relatedly, that $X \vert \ (f^{m-1} - f^{n-1})$, $f^{s+1} \vert \ (f^{m+s} - f^{n+s})$, and finally since $(f^{m-s}(X) - f^{n-s}(X))\circ f^s(\alpha) = 0$, that $(X - f^s(\alpha)) \vert \ (f^{m-s}(X) - f^{n-s}(X)), \ \forall s = 0\dots n $.

Can we do anything useful with this information?

Comment: If $r\in R$ then the minimal polynomial is $x-r$.

Comment: So $f^n(x) = x-nr$, and we are just talking about the additive order of $r$.